# File is uploaded in the private library or public library

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdocument

I have written a triger (**before insert**) on **ContentVersion** object and I am checking that the user is going to upload the file in private library or public library.

According to my findings which I got from the documentation of ContentVersion object, there is PublishStatus field in ContentVersion object which determines the library(private/public). But I am not getting the exact value in the PublishStatus field.

There are three possible values for this field

- R => file is uploaded in private library.
- P => file is uploaded in public library.
- U => file uploading is interrupted.

But each time in the **before insert** trigger I got **U**.

can anyone help me to identify this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to populate `FirstPublishLocationId`, according to [ContentVersion documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm):

> ID of the location where the version was first published. If the
>   version is first published into a user's personal library or My Files,
>   the field will contain the ID of the user who owns the personal
>   library or My Files. If the first version is published into a public
>   library, the field will contain the ID of that library.
>
> This field is only set the first time a version is published via the
>   API. It isn't set when a version is published in Salesforce CRM
>   Content or uploaded in Salesforce Files or. After the version is
>   published, it is a read-only field.
>
> If you don't set a FirstPublishLocationId via the API, this field
>   defaults to the user's personal library, unless Origin is set to H,
>   then this field defaults to My Files.

You can also reference `Special Access Rules` section from the link above where they have listed all requirements for the users trying to publish to public library.